# Flutter - How to count data based on ID in List

Tags: android, ios, dart, flutter

I have a `List<Comment>` from all foods.

```
[
 {
   comment_id: '...'
   food_id: '...'
   comment: '...'
 }, 
 {
   comment_id: '...'
   food_id: '...'
   comment: '...'
 },

  ....

]
```

I want to know how to count the number of comments based on `food_id` in Flutter?
Any answer is very helpful.

Comment: Can you please add more concrete info. Perhaps some concrete example data and what the expected result would be. I don't understand what the problem is here.

Comment: what is the data structure that represent relationship of `product_id` and `Comment` ?

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer i have edited the question

Comment: @PeteHouston im sorry, i mean `product_id` is `food_id`

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can use `where(...)` to filter a list and `.length` the get the result length.

```
var comments = <Comment>[...];
var count = comments.where((c) => c.product_id == someProductId).length;
```

Comment: its work, thanks yeah

Comment: Glad to hear :D

Comment: :D
Hi sir, do you know why when after retrieving data from the server then adding it to the list, the latest data appears from bottom, not from top.
how to make the data list taken in the order of new (top) to old (bottom) as in the news list in general

Comment: Hard to tell. Way too little information. I'd suggest you create a new question with more detail. How you render the data, how you add new data, ...

Comment: There is no need to convert the `Iterable<Comment>` to `toList()`, you can call `.length` directly on the `Iterable`.

Answer (score 3):

This code will iterate over the comments and obtain the number of comments which are about the product_id_param specified.

```
int number_of_comments = comments.fold(
    0,
    (sum, comment) => (comment.product_id == product_id_param) ? sum + 1 : sum
);
```